# Why does binding `onEach` inside launch cause `MutableSharedFlow` events to be lost?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

This test passes:

```
@Test
fun passingTest() {
    val emitter = MutableSharedFlow<Int>();
    var total = 0;

    val handler = emitter.onEach {  // <--- onEach bound outside of `launch`
        total += it;
        println("-> $it : total: $total")
    }

    GlobalScope.launch {
        handler.collect()
    }

    runBlocking {
        for (i in 1..11) {
            emitter.emit(1);
        }
    }

    assert(total == 11);
}
```

However, if I move the `.onEach` into `launch` it doesn't work any more:

```
> expected:<11> but was:<0>
> Expected :11
> Actual   :0
```

```
@Test
fun failingTest() {
    val emitter = MutableSharedFlow<Int>();
    var total = 0;

    GlobalScope.launch {
        emitter.onEach { // <--- Bind inside of launch
            total += it;
            println("-> $it : total: $total")
        }.collect()
    }

    runBlocking {
        for (i in 1..11) {
            emitter.emit(1);
        }
    }

    assertEquals(11, total);
}
```

What's going on? Why is my `onEach` handler getting lost when it's attached inside the launch scope?

Comment: Doug, I noticed that the first test case flacks. I tried it on my own and sometimes total is 0 as in the second test case or some other value. I bet some kind of race condition happens, therefore sometimes values are emit after onEach flow terminated

Comment: I conducted some research and updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

So I tried both test cases on my own, logging the blocks of `GlobalScope.launch` and `runBlocking`.

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    println("launch")
    handler.collect()
}

runBlocking {
    for (i in 1..11) {
        println(i)
        emitter.emit(1);
    }
}
println(total)
```

This test case gives me random output each run. E.g: "12345678910110" even without "launch", sometimes it works as it is expected, sometimes it start collecting after some values are already emitted and therefore the value of `total` is less than 11.

```
launch
1
2
-> 1 : total: 1
3
-> 1 : total: 2
4
-> 1 : total: 3
5
-> 1 : total: 4
6
-> 1 : total: 5
7
-> 1 : total: 6
8
-> 1 : total: 7
9
-> 1 : total: 8
10
-> 1 : total: 9
11
-> 1 : total: 10
-> 1 : total: 11
11
```

In the same time, running second test case several times did not get me to seeing ]total] greater than 0. But I noticed that `GlobalScope` code executes at random time, so I can see `launch` output before the output of `runBlocking` or in the middle of it, but `onEach`'s output is not present still.

I decided to log `collect` call itself

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    println("launch")
    emitter.onEach {
        total += it;
        println("-> $it : total: $total")
    }.collect {
        "collecting"
    }
}
```

And noticed that it **does not get called at all**. Since the time, at which code of `GlobalScope.launch` gets called, does not matter, I bet that the scope of handler matters.
`onEach` works as a listener, therefore emitting in `runBlocking` updates it in the first test case sometimes. And when `collect` gets called in the right time, it does collecting.

But the listening cannot happen in the other scope and therefore in the second case you will always receive an empty flow. If you add one more `GlobalScope.launch` with emitting something in the second case, it will get processed by handler and collected.

Comment: "Since your flow is declared in the scope, where blocking happens, there is no way for another thread to perform reads to emitter." ? But, the flow is declared in the same scope that is blocking *in the test that passes*, not in the test that fails.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I will fix my answer